# Right way of streaming a MP3 using PHP

Tags: php, stream, streaming, mp3

How would you correctly stream a MP3 file while not linking to the source file?

Some examples on stackoverflow use octet-stream others then say that u shouldn't use octet-stream for MP3

My project creates a teporary url for each mp3 file to prevent hotlinking.
This is the code that I'm currently using

```
class stream{
private $path = "";
private $stream = "";
private $buffer = 102400;
private $start = -1;
private $end = -1;
private $size = 0;
function __construct($filePath) {
    ini_set('memory_limit', '300M');
    $this -> path = $filePath;
}

private function open() {
    if (!($this -> stream = fopen($this -> path, 'rb'))) {
        die('Could not open stream for reading');
    }
}

private function setHeader() {
    ob_get_clean();
    header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public");
    header("Expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 2592000) . ' GMT');
    header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', @filemtime($this -> path)) . ' GMT');
    $this -> start = 0;
    $this -> size = filesize($this -> path);
    $this -> end = $this -> size - 1;
    header("Accept-Ranges: 0-".$this -> end);
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
        $c_start = $this -> start;
        $c_end = $this -> end;
        list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
        if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
            exit;
        }
        if ($range == '-') {
            $c_start = $this -> size - substr($range, 1);
        } else {
            $range = explode('-', $range);
            $c_start = $range[0];
            $c_end = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $c_end;
        }
        $c_end = ($c_end > $this -> end) ? $this -> end : $c_end;
        if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $this -> size - 1 || $c_end >= $this -> size) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
            exit;
        }
        $this -> start = $c_start;
        $this -> end = $c_end;
        $length = $this -> end - $this -> start + 1;
        fseek($this -> stream, $this -> start);
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        header("Content-Length: ".$length);
        header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/".$this -> size);
    } else {
        header("Content-Length: ".$this -> size);
    }
}
private function end() {
    fclose($this -> stream);
    exit;
}
private function stream() {
    $i = $this -> start;
    set_time_limit(0);
    while (!feof($this -> stream) && $i <= $this -> end) {
        $bytesToRead = $this -> buffer;
        if (($i + $bytesToRead) > $this -> end) {
            $bytesToRead = $this -> end - $i + 1;
        }
        $data = fread($this -> stream, $bytesToRead);
        echo $data;
        flush();
        $i += $bytesToRead;
    }
}
function start() {
    $this -> open();
    $this -> setHeader();
    $this -> stream();
    $this -> end();
}
}
```

But this sometimes freezes and makes it impossible to play another file or even close/refresh the Chrome-Tab

So is this the right way of streaming a MP3 file through PHP

Comment: Chrome likes to seek and requests only parts of the file, so you need to make sure you absolutely support ranges.

Comment: I'm also not sure why you make a class for this, it's only for mpeg and looks more like it's high maintenance. A function would suffice.